# is it efficient to define random number generator inside function integrator?

Tags: c++

Consider an Euler integrator that solves a stochastic differential equation:

```cpp
void euler(vector<double> &x0,
           vector<double> &dxdt,
           const double dt)
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 rng(rd());
    std::normal_distribution<> dist(0, 1);
    f(dxdt, t, dt)        
    for (int i=0; i<x0.size(); ++i)
       x0[i] += dxdt[i] * dt + sqrt(dt) * 0.01 * dist(rng);
}
```

is this efficient to define the random generator for each time step integration?
and probably there is a better option?
another problem with this method is that when I try to fix the random seed

```
const unsigned int seed = 2;
std::mt19937 rng(seed);
```

for each time step, I get the same random numbers and this affects the answer.

Comment: I don't get why I get downvote? please comment on the reason.

Comment: Didn't vote at all, but I see a lot of questions like this where someone asks a question about something that they could easily measure.  The other thing is that you're asking why using the same seed yields the same results.  That's how pseudorandom generation works.  You should only seed your generator once.  And so, what you've done is the _wrong_ way to do it.  Nothing to do with whether it's "efficient" or not.  By seeding a new generator every time, you lose the intrinsic properties of the generator and instead rely on the randomness of the device.

Comment: IMO, it is better to define these objects outside the function. I don't know if `std::random_device`, `std::mt19937` and `std::normal_distribution<>` are "simple" objects, but yes your program's efficiency is likely to benefit from them being defined outside the function and pass them by reference `&`. @paddy provided a much better comment than mine.

Comment: (passing rng as argument) yeah, I thought about it, but I have not seen anybody use that before and I don't know if this is common. Maybe confuse ppl that see my codes later.

Comment: [`std::sample`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sample)/[`std::shuffle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) are std examples using random number generator as parameter.

Comment: why do you care about efficiency at all when the code is not doing the right thing?

Comment: without fixing the seed, it works, but I need the seed for checking the correctness. I have seen some questions about passing rng as an argument,  probably wrapping the rng with a class would do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeding a PRNG if often costly and should usually only be done *once* during the whole program run so, no, this is not efficient.

I suggest that you break the creation of the PRNG out into a separate function that has a `static` PRNG (only initialized once).

```
std::mt19937& rng() {
    static std::mt19937 instance{std::random_device{}()};
    return instance;
}
```

or, if the PRNG is going to be used from multiple threads simultaneously:

```
std::mt19937& rng() {
    thread_local std::mt19937 instance{std::random_device{}()};
    return instance;
}
```

You can then use `rng()` in every function that needs a PRNG:

```
void euler(std::vector<double>& x0,
           std::vector<double>& dxdt,
           const double dt) 
{
    // Now use rng() instead of rng in here
}
```

Comment: I'd prefer `template <typename URBG = std::mt19937&> void euler(std::vector<double>& x0, std::vector<double>& dxdt, const double dt, URBG&& rng = rng())` than tying it to `rng()`

Comment: @Caleth That would certainly be more flexible but unless different PRNG:s will be needed in the program I think it's a bit overkill. If `euler` is going to be a part of a library and the users of the library are supposed to be able to select any PRNG, then I'm 100% for your suggestion.